# Use of CSS Helper Class

Tags: css, helper, abstraction

I try to code CSS in "Help Class Style" today and many developers on Twitter said it was a bad practice.

Here is an example:

```
<span class="et-margin-top-30 et-width-400 et-display-inline">
    <p class="et-common-frame-shadow et-inner-img-shadow">
        <img class="et-common-frame-img" src="img3.jpg"/>
    </p>
    <h3 class="et-margin-top-10 et-fontsize-26 et-fontweight-bold">foo</h3>
    <p class="et-margin-top-10">bar</p>
</span>
```

Why is it a bad practice? When should we use a helper class such as .clear?

Answer (score 5):

The idea of *styling via CSS* is separation between content and styling. Your content is in HTML and CSS provides the information on how that should be visually displayed. If you want to change one, you can do so without changing the other.

By naming your classes `et-margin-top-30`, you're putting the styling information back into your HTML. You may as well write `style="margin-top: 30px"`. Because if you decide that that element should have a *50* pixel margin after all, you need to change both the CSS *and* the HTML. That's why it's bad style.

You should rather name your HTML elements by their function (e.g. `class="headline"`, or `class="call-to-action"`), then describe in your CSS how that *headline* or that *call-to-action* should be styled. If you want to change that later, you can do so by simply editing your CSS, the HTML doesn't need to change.

Not to mention that if you're using Javascript to manipulate elements, using `document.getElementsByClassName('et-margin-top-30')` a) makes it very hard to understand the meaning of your scripts and HTML structure and b) requires that you modify your HTML, CSS *and Javascript* every time you want to tweak the visual appearance of an element. Using descriptive class names becomes doubly important then.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do there looks horrible. It looks like you have a class for all different styling attributes. Not only will it make your HTML unreadable, but it will also enlarge the file size.

What if an element has 15 styles "attached" to it. Will it have 15 classes?

I also think this will only make this slower to render (this is just something I just made up and for which I have no proof), because it has to look up all those classes.

I don't see any difference in doing `<p style="color: red;"></p>`.